# Recommended setup for Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm interested in using a MBaaS service, and I've gotten many recommendations for Firebase and Parse Server, but I'm having a hard time evaluating the latter. I'm a native iOS dev, and have only used PHP and MySQL to write basic web services in the past. I don't know anything about what hosting providers are good, what services like Heroku does, etc. What's the best way to get this set up for the average developer with an app that shouldn't have more than a few hundred thousand users at most?

The only restriction is that I will absolutely not use AWS for anything, including hosting. Had an account stolen one time, and they refused to help me get it back even after verifying my identity. Never doing business with them again.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase. Parse will cease and desist all operations on January 2017.

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: That is correct, but *Parse Server* is open source, and will persist indefinitely.

Comment: If I had to choose beetween Parse & Firebase, I'd go for Parse-Server, because nothing prevents Firebase to be closed too in the future, and that will avoid you a migration. By using Parse-Server, you'll already be using a stable open-source platform